# mailchimp api 2.0 subscribe through php?

Tags: php, mailchimp

I need an example of how to subscribe a email address to mailchimp newsletter.

Please check new api link here:
https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mailchimp-api-php

This is new malichimp api and I am not sure how to use it. :(

For MailChimp 2.0 API, not for 1.3.

Please somebody provide an example on how to subscribe user to mailchimp.

Thank You.

Edit1: Already tried following code, but not working:

```
$merge_vars = array('MM1'=>$mm1);
$MailChimp = new Mailchimp($apikey);
$result = $MailChimp->call('lists/subscribe', array(
            'id'                => $listid,
            'email'             => array('email'=>$email),
            'merge_vars'        => $merge_vars,
            'double_optin'      => false,
            'update_existing'   => true,
            'replace_interests' => false,
            'send_welcome'      => false,
        ));
    print_r($result);
```

But not working. Throwing following error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function call() on a non-object in subscribe.php on line 22

Comment: Great tutorial here: http://code-epicenter.com/how-to-integrate-your-website-with-mailchimp-api-using-php/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Referring to the documentation, this should be like so:

```
$merge_vars = array('MM1'=>$mm1);
$listid = 'YOURLISTID';
$MailChimp = new Mailchimp($apikey);
$result = $MailChimp->lists->subscribe($listid,
                                        array('email'=>"contact@twittstrap.com"),
                                        $merge_vars,
                                        false,
                                        true,
                                        false,
                                        false
                                       );
    print_r($result);
```

Tested and working.

Comment: what is $mm1? in $merge_vars

Comment: List ID is the list in which the user will subscibe, it can be found in mailchimp once you create a new list.

Answer (score 9):

this might be helpful for some, simple mailchimp subscriber API code sample with php

[mailchimp subscriber API code example in PHP](http://codeandfun.blogspot.com/2014/02/mailchimp-api-subscribe-user-email.html)

Answer (score 4):

Here is with Try & Catch (example for when dup emails)

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
include_once 'Mailchimp.php';

$api_key = '';
$list_id = '';


$email = 'hello@email.com';
$merge_vars = array();

$Mailchimp = new Mailchimp($api_key);
$Mailchimp_Lists = new Mailchimp_Lists($Mailchimp);

try{
    $subscriber = $Mailchimp_Lists->subscribe(
        $list_id,
        array('email'=>htmlentities($email)),
        $merge_vars,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false
    );
    echo json_encode(array('status' => !empty($subscriber['leid'])?'submitted':'error'));
} catch(Mailchimp_Error $e){
    echo json_encode(array(
            'status' => 'error',
            'message' => $e->getMessage()
        ));
}
```

Readmore about `subscribe()` : https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/subscribe.php

Answer (score 3):

Subscribe through php using curl.

```
$apikey     = 'xxxxxxxxxx'; //your apikey
$listId     = 'xxxxxxxxxx';  // your list id
$endpoint   = "http://yourdatacenter.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/";      // find your datacenter in your apikey( xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-us13 <= this is your datacenter)
$auth       = base64_encode( 'user:'. $apikey );
$data       = array(
                    'apikey'        => $apikey,
                    'email_address' => 'yourvalid_email_address',
                    'status'        => 'subscribed',
                    'merge_fields'  => array());

$json_data = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint.$listId.'/members/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',
                                            'Authorization: Basic '.$auth));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/2.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo "<pre>";  // Response form mailchimp
print_r(json_decode($result,true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is example may it helpful for some one.

[mailchimp subscriber api example](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/listsubscribe.func.php)

Comment: OP said "For MailChimp 2.0 API, not for 1.3."