# mailchimp http error: you must specify a apikey

Tags: php, json, curl, mailchimp

I'm the using MailChimp 2.0 api and trying to post a lists/subscribe call using php.  The call is returning an error "You must specify a apikey value".

Here's the code that makes the post:

```
  function json_post ($url, $params)
  {
    print '<p>url = ' . $url . '</p>';
    $data = json_encode ($params);
    print '<p>data = ' . $data . '</p>';

    $handle = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt ($handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt ($handle, CURLOPT_POST_FIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt ($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt ($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('Content-Type: application/json',
                                                     'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)));

    $result = curl_exec ($handle);
    print '<p>curl_error: ' . curl_errno ($handle) . '</p>';
    return $result;
  }
```

The print statements show:

```
url = https://us10.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/lists/subscribe.json

data = {"apikey":"...","id":"...","email":{"email":"test1@abc.com"},"merge_vars":{"groupings":{"name":"test"}}}

curl_error: 0

{"status":"error","code":-100,"name":"ValidationError","error":"You must specify a apikey value"}
```

I presume there's something wrong with the syntax.  The api key is cut & pasted from my mailchimp account page.  I've tried it with and without the -us10 suffix.  Any ideas?

Comment: Seems there is a [wrapper](https://github.com/mailchimp/mcapi2-php-examples) class for hands when using the `v2.0` API

Comment: @darkbee - I did come across the 2.0 example you cite.  It is so enormous that I have no idea what part of it is relevant to my issue.  Is it really worth the time to dig into it?  I was hoping my posted question is straight forward and easy to fix.

Comment: Well.. this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427405/mailchimp-api-2-0-subscribe-through-php) has an answer + example using that wrapper though ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To subscribe:

```
$email='';
$apikey='';
$listId='';

    $data = array(
                    'email_address'=>$email,
                    'apikey'=>$apikey,
                    'merge_vars' => array(),
                    'id' => $listId,
                    'double_optin' => false,
                    'update_existing' => true,
                    'replace_interests' => false,
                    'send_welcome' => false,
                    'email_type' => 'html'
            );
    $submit_url = "http://us6.api.mailchimp.com/1.3/?method=listSubscribe";


$payload = json_encode($data); 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $submit_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode($payload));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$data = json_decode($result);
if (isset($data->error) and $data->error){
        //Error
} else {
        //Ok
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but I still get the same error.  Perhaps I have something subtly wrong but I don't see it.  It seems the main difference between your code and mine is you are using version 1.3 and I'm trying to use 2.0.  Any other ideas why I'm getting the apikey error?

Comment: I'll check the new version of the api on my website and see if works or not ;)

Comment: Millan - The solution was stupidly simple.  I mistyped CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS (still shown incorrectly in my original post).  There are some other differences between your code and mine but I think that was the only significant change.

Answer (score 1):

Cases where you get "API Key Missing" but the API Key is definitely there usually comes from JSON Syntax errors, which MailChimp doesn't catch specifically. You'll want to make sure that JSON isn't getting double-encoded or anything like that.

In this case, it is probably `CURLOPT_POST_FIELDS` -- the actual [PHP Constant](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.constants.php) you're looking for is `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

You should use Guzzle or another HTTP library to ensure you're not double-encoding your JSON or otherwise getting tripped up by the Curl library's verbosity.

Comment: I haven't tried them.  I just looked them up (I'm a newbie at PHP) and I need to ask: how would they help with the fundamental problem?  I'm currently using json_encode so, if I have a syntax problem, it's at a higher level than encoding, isn't it?  How do I find out what the syntax problem is, assuming that's the case?

Comment: This is a comment. Answers don't require furthermore questions

Comment: I removed the "question" in the post, since it seems to have confused some folks. It was a polite way of recommending that @PeriHartman try a less convoluted library. I also added another possible answer.